# GPS - Speed doesn't update as should - EM408 & Arduino Mega & GSM

Tags: c, gps, arduino, gsm, i2c

I'm developing a system that will get the GPS signal and send it though the GSM with information about position, speed and temperature from some digital sensors.

Currently I'm using the GPS EM408, the Arduino mega plus the GSM board (official one).

The problem is that the GPS (by the library TinyGPSPlus) gives me the same speed for long time or sometimes give me 0km/h.

The sketch works like this:

```
loop() 
{ 
  getGPSData() - ~ 1 sec to execute and take one data from the GPS. 
  getSensors() - ~ 1 sec to execute and take one data from the digital sensors. 
  sendData() - ~ 6 n 10 secs to send the data through the internet. 
}
```

The whole process takes around 10 ~ 15 secs to be completed.

If I remove the sendData() and the system starts getting the GPS information each second the speed value works perfectly but if I get the data from the GPS each 12 secs (because of the GSM delay) the speed doesn't work as expected.

I understand that the problem is because the library TinyGPSPlus calculate the speed between two points and the getGPSData() only takes one information each loop and the next point has 15 secs of difference.

Although I've added a "for(i=0;i<=4;i++)" to the getGPSData() enforcing it to get at least 4 times of position before the GSM send it over the internet, now is working better but still getting the wrong value or sometimes it freezes to the same speedy for long time.

I've tried to add a second board and put both to communicate with I2C turning it "dual core", where one board will be getting the data from the GPS each second and another one will send though the data each 15 secs, but the GSM freezes sometimes when the I2C is connected :(.

Does anyone has any clue how to do it?

Comment: The speed should be valid in relation to the timestamp of the location. And if that was 11 secods ago, then it still should show the speed which was driven at that 11 sec ago. Speed should not be calculated by positiona change, it should directly been takemn from the GPS attribute "speed (over ground)"

Comment: I've checked the serial communication between the GPS and the Arduino, therewith I've detected that the problem was because there is a gap in the middle of the communication.

My code has a WHILE() to keep taking information from the serial while data is coming from the serial, but sometimes the connection between both has a small stop (the gap) and it was closing the WHILE(). 

I added another WHILE() to keep checking the serial for at least 2 seconds and it solved the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is not good to add  "`for(i=0;i<=4;i++)`" loop like you tried and furthermore to add duplicate device - so far from the solution. Instead you should unbind `getGPSdata()` from `sendData()` in other words separate the calls of them into different tasks.

I can imagine it is a simple Round-robin scheduling provided with that library, not a complete RTOS in there, isn't it? Nevertheless, put them into different tasks, loops or whatever. Probably you will need to arrange a buffer to collect GPS data to and sending out this from the buffer from a different loop.

Hope it helps.